# Logotype on the glass

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I am not a professional designer (not a designer at all), but some time ago I found this image from the logotype bundle:

[image: example of logo on glass]

I would like a professional advice: is it a Photoshop? And, if yes, where can I find a tutorial or lesson on how to do something similar?

I do not actually ask for the place I can find the lesson, but what to search for. Searching for something like "logo on the glass" gives me a lot of results of painting on fogged glass - not really the thing I need.

Comment: Yes, definitely. A bit another sample: http://higher.sk/en/files/uploads/images/0302.jpg  As you can see, a bit different perspective deformation, a little bit of blur, and more transparency.

Comment: Just looks so real for me, as I am not an expert

Comment: @Vnovak I'm totaly out of my leage, but wonder if it can be done in GIMP 2. Just add a text and logo en a glass door picture. If yes, what shold I learn? Thanks.

Comment: @Horaciux, sorry never user gimp before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this logo was made with simple graphics. but then a photoshop mockup for photo-realistic image was used. You can also do that. Make your simple logo in illustrator or CorelDraw using pen tool and then find a good PSD photo-realistic template for it.

Comment: Thank you! Just downloaded similar ones, as searching for `Logo PSD mockup glass` did the job for me